# Why is get_pages() returning a boolean?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

I have created a custom post type that I want to use to allow people to add an arbitrary number of sections to the homepage of my theme. I want to loop through all posts of that type and include their contents in the page. My problem is that calling `get_pages()` with `'post_type' => 'home_section'` seems to be returning a boolean, not an array.

Here is the code I'm using to test:

```
<?php
   $hp_sections = get_pages(array('post_type' => 'home_section'));
   echo '<!-- $hp_sections type: ', gettype($hp_sections), ', value: ', $hp_sections, ' -->';
?>
```

When I view source on my page I get:

```
<!-- $hp_sections type: boolean, value:  -->
```

I'm pretty new to both PHP and Wordpress so I'm assuming I'm making some sort of dumb mistake. I'd like to know both what is wrong with the above code and what the recommended way to get all pages of a given type and iterate over them inside a template is.

Comment: From the [Codex page for `get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages): *[Returns] An array containing all the Pages matching the request, **or false on failure**.* [Emphasis mine.]  Try doing `var_dump( $hp_sections );` -- if it spits out "Boolean false" then there's something amiss with your request (or there aren't any valid posts to return).  Also: try using [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) instead of `get_pages()`.

Comment: @PatJ Oops, I guess I missed that second part when reading the manual. `get_posts()` does seem to work and I'm not sure why the analogous query is failing with `get_pages()`. The docs seem to indicate that `get_posts()` and `get_pages()` should be used in different situations but never really elaborate on the criteria for each. Would you consider this an appropriate place to use `get_posts()` over `get_pages()`?

Comment: Yes, I'd use `get_posts()` instead of `get_pages()`. Generally the only time I'll consider using `get_pages()` is if I actually want Pages.  Even then I might try using `get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'page' ) );` first to see if it does what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically I've had better luck using `get_posts()` over `get_pages()`.  Especially in the case of a custom post type, I'd recommend using something like

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'home_section',
);
$hp_sections = get_posts( $args );
```

instead of using `get_pages()`.

#### Reference

- [`get_posts()` on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts)

Comment: To add to this, `get_pages` I believe only supports hierarchical post types. So unless `home_section` is hierarchical, it short circuits and returns false.